# Kit Specification Screen cannot load RevisionID when creating Acumatica report designer

Tags: acumatica

I've created the report about Kit Specification and have 2 parameters:
1. Kit InventoryID
2. RevisionID
for user input to show the report.
This below is my parameters

KitInventoryID
=Report.GetFieldSchema('INKitSpecHdr.KitInventoryID')

RevisionID
=Report.GetFieldSchema('INKitSpecHdr.RevisionID')

and this is the result:

[image]

it didn't show the revisionID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the report for your RevisionID parameter view name, use this syntax to pass the dependent report parameter as a selector parameter...

```
=Report.GetFieldSchema('INKitSpecHdr.RevisionID',KitInventoryID)
```

We have had similar needs for some of our custom tables, however there was a need to have an optional pxselector paramter for it to work which I do not see on INKitSpecHdr.RevisionID selector. Hope this works.

If not you might need to make your own DAC/Selector for revision and use a selector on the RevisionID field like this...

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<INKitSpecHdr.revisionID,
        Where<INKitSpecHdr.kitInventoryID, Equal<Optional<INKitSpecHdr.kitInventoryID>>>>))]
```

From what I can remember, this is what we did to get something similar to work.